# Is it safe to visit Cairo in 2014?

Tags: transit, security, cairo

I will have some time between flights in Cairo. I would love to visit the city but with all recent events I don't know how safe it is to visit it. Specially because it would be around 20h (so night time).

Comment: I have around 4 hours. It would be a short visit, and mostly by night.

Comment: Define "safe?" There is risk in everything. Are you asking about risk of death? Risk of being robbed? Risk of... ? And what is an acceptable level of risk to you?

Comment: @Flimzy I understand your point, but aren't you being a bit too analytical? Cairo has been through a rough time. I want to know if there is risk and what kind of risk it is for an average person. Than I can evaluate my chances. If I was a "rambo" I would mention it.

Comment: @pnuts you have a point. Thank you. That would be my next search.

Comment: Not really safe yet. A colleague of mine was killed in the street 2 months ago, she was walking back home and the robber didn't just let her go after he stole, he killed her in an ugly way (stabbing her in the face, she bled to death). BTW, she was living in what's suppose to be a high class area!

Comment: @nsn: I think you can ask that question, then: "Has the political situation in Cairo stabilized for tourism?" If you look at the other questions we get about ["travel safety"](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/37472/444), you should have an appreciation for the fact that what one person thinks is perfectly safe, another might think is incredibly risky.

Comment: @Flimzy my question goes behond that. Even if the political situation is stable enough to visit Cairo, the civil support systems may not be. I just want to know if, as a individual foreigner individual what my chances are.

Answer (score 1):

I believe most of [my answer on this when it came up in 2012](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/2625/101) is still relevant - safety is what you are willing to risk.

Impressively for a government website, the US State Department has a great quote on safety:

> "There is nobody better at protecting you than yourself.". Be careful,
>   keep informed, be safe."

Most countries have a travel advisory / security / safety website. the US State Department has [this page for learning about your destination](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country.html) - enter in Egypt, and you can see what they have to say.

One thing, as mentioned in a Rick Steves podcast I was listening to recently, is that these sites have to err on the side of caution.  If they didn't mention a danger and something happened, they'd get blamed for not warning you. As a result, they warn you about every possible risk.  So take it in, but realise that a risky or dangerous place doesn't necessarily preclude you from visiting.  Indeed, sometimes the crime/uprising/protests are taking place in jungles (Colombia), regions (Afghanistan) or other spots that you're not planning on visiting yourself.  Research, read the information, and then ultimately, you have to decide how safe it is for yourself.

Some people will still go, others will decide against it. We can't decide for you.